# MongoDB $gt/$lt operators with prices stored as strings

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query my database for prices greater than/less than a user specified number. In my database, prices are stored like so:

```
{price: "300.00"}
```

According to the docs, this should work:

```
db.products.find({price: {$gt:30.00}}).pretty()
```

But I get no results returned. I've also tried `{price: {$gt:30}}`.

What am I missing here?

It it because the prices are stored as a string rather than a number in the DB? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you intend to use $gt with strings, you will have to use regex, which is not great in terms of performance. It is easier to just create a new field which holds the number value of price or change this field type to int/double. A javascript version should also work, like so:

```
db.products.find("this.price > 30.00")
```

as js will convert it to number before use. However, indexes won't work on this query.

Comment: Woah, had no idea you could use javascript in the query. Awesome, thanks. I'll convert it to a number anyhow but this helps a lot.

Comment: You would want a price to be int only @Jascination the JS execution will use no index, as such it is pretty much useless in this case, easier to just make your schema right

Comment: Please avoid $where, it is run in JavaScript and gives a large performance hit. $gt can also be used with other types.

Comment: Very slow this way.   Huge performance impact.  The strings compared aren’t analogous.  It should work using “30.00”

Answer (score 24):

`$gt` is an operator that can work on any type:

```
db.so.drop();
db.so.insert( { name: "Derick" } );
db.so.insert( { name: "Jayz" } );
db.so.find( { name: { $gt: "Fred" } } );
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffbe6c16473d7b84172d58"), "name" : "Jayz" }
```

If you want to compare against a number with `$gt` or `$lt`, then the value in your document also needs to be a number. Types in MongoDB are strict and do **not** auto-convert like they f.e. would do in PHP. In order to solve your issue, make sure you store the prices as numbers (floats or ints):

```
db.so.drop();
db.so.insert( { price: 50.40 } );
db.so.insert( { price: 29.99 } );
db.so.find( { price: { $gt: 30 } } );
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51ffbf2016473d7b84172d5b"), "price" : 50.4 }
```

Answer (score 17):

Starting `Mongo 4.0`, there is a new [`$toDouble`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/#exp._S_toDouble) aggregation operator which converts from various types to double (in this case from a string):

```
// { price: "300.00" }
// { price: "4.2" }
 db.collection.find({ $expr: { $gt: [{ $toDouble: "$price" }, 30] } })
// { price: "300.00" }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have newer version of mongodb then you can do this:

```
$expr: {
          $gt: [
             { $convert: { input: '$price', to: 'decimal' } },
             { $convert: { input: '0.0', to: 'decimal' } }
               ]
              }
```

$expr operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/

$convert opetator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can convert the values to Int, as per:
http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-change-a-field-type-from-String-to-Integer-in-mongodb

```
var convert = function(document){
var intValue = parseInt(document.field, 10);
  db.collection.update(
    {_id:document._id}, 
    {$set: {field: intValue}}
  );
}

db.collection.find({field: {$type:2}},{field:1}).forEach(convert)
```