# mongoDB query Result Output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a following documents in my collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539c118b310c022c947b0055"),
    "term" : "aero storm tour",
    "year" : "2015",
    "month" : "06",
    "day" : "01",
    "hour" : "17",
    "dayofyear" : "4",
    "weekofyear" : "22",
    "productcount" : 0,
    "count" : 22
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c118b310c022c947b1145"),
    "term" : "aero",
    "year" : "2015",
    "month" : "06",
    "day" : "01",
    "hour" : "17",
    "dayofyear" : "4",
    "weekofyear" : "22",
    "productcount" : 0,
    "count" : 21
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c992b310c022c947b0055"),
    "term" : "aero storm tour",
    "year" : "2015",
    "month" : "06",
    "day" : "01",
    "hour" : "17",
    "dayofyear" : "1",
    "weekofyear" : "22",
    "productcount" : 0,
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c118b123c022c947b0055"),
    "term" : "aero storm tour",
    "year" : "2014",
    "month" : "06",
    "day" : "01",
    "hour" : "17",
    "dayofyear" : "364",
    "weekofyear" : "22",
    "productcount" : 0,
    "count" : 32
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c223c310c022c947b0055"),
    "term" : "aero storm tour",
    "year" : "2014",
    "month" : "06",
    "day" : "01",
    "hour" : "17",
    "dayofyear" : "365",
    "weekofyear" : "22",
    "productcount" : 0,
    "count" : 22
}
```

I need to calculate the sum of `count` and `term`based on the condition specified by  `year` and `dayofyear` .

My query :

```js
db.tq.aggregate(
   {$match:
      {$or :[
            { $and :[{dayofyear:{ $gte : "1", $lte : "4" }},{year : "2015"}]},
            { $and :[{dayofyear:{ $gte : "363", $lte : "365" }},{year : "2014"}]}
            ]
      }
    },
      {$group:{

               _id :"$term",
       totalcount : {
                     $sum : "$count"
                    }
   }
 },
 {
$sort : {totalcount : -1}
 }

)
```

Here , I have manually specified the dayofyear as between 1 & 4 year 2015 AND dayofyear 363 & 365 year 2014.

But it does not give the desired result. Can any one point out the mistake in my query ?

Comment: You are using $gte on a field which is a string.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039358/mongodb-gt-lt-operators-with-prices-stored-as-strings

Comment: More to the point: "400" is less than "8". That is how lexical string matching works. You need to convert them to numeric values.

Comment: Also store the "dates" as `Date` objects. You can do all the same things with proper `Date` objects and it takes a "lot" less storage to do so.

Comment: The Query gives the correct result with numerical value.But I cannot change the existing model.How can I achieve it with string field.I need to write Java API for all the query.So,any suggestion?

Comment: Actually your query gives the correct result ( with these parameters and the sample data, but don't count on it ) anyway. But @ZeMoon already gave you a link where one suggestion there is to use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) since it is JavaScript. `parseInt` or even properly casting to `Date` objects within that logic are your friends here. Also take to to your boss **change the data**, and the whole posse here will gang up on him/her for you :)

Comment: @BlakesSeven : I ran the query on a bigger data set and at some cases it fails. I don't understand why ? Logically, it should work i guess.Am i missing something ?

Comment: Did you do "everything" I said? No? Of course you did not. What you are missing is reading what I have said here. Do you really need a full answer to spell it all out, because we can give that but it likely isn't going to help many people. Actually reading and understanding the comments already made should be enough.