# mongoose, how to correct query String datatype in the case of multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here are some answers:

[go!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039358/mongodb-gt-lt-operators-with-prices-stored-as-strings)

But, I did not try to succeed  in the case of multiple conditions, use mongoose.

For example:

The Schema:

```
var data = new Schema({
    price:{type: String},
    productnumber:{type: String},
    });
```

The operation:

```
thedata.find({
   "price":"this.price> 30.00",
   "productnumber": "this.productnumber >= 100"
},function(err, result) {

});
```

or

```
thedata.find({
   "this.price> 30.00",
   "this.productnumber >= 100"
},function(err, result) {

});
```

These are not the correct operation..,How do I set up?

---

*I can not reset the data type,the schema not my design and the system is on-line working...

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the implicit version of **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/where/)** in this case, besides that it's very inefficient as it is run in JavaScript and gives a large performance hit, you can use the native mongo comparison operators like **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt)** and **[`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte)** for this query.

The following example shows this:

```
thedata.find({
   "price": { "$gt": 30.00" },
   "productnumber": { "$gte": "100" }
}, function(err, result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: the data type is string,when I using the  $gt, $gte..etc,will get the wrong  search results. For 
example:when I search  month> 2,the 3~9 month can be successfully found,but the 11~12 month is not fund.
Because the string 2 > string 11.