# cast a string to number in mongo aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to cast a string to number to perform range operations like `"$gte"` in mongo aggregation query?

For example if a field is like "quantity":"3" is there in a document, i need to query it like `{"quantity":{"$gte":3}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB $gt/$lt operators with prices stored as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039358/mongodb-gt-lt-operators-with-prices-stored-as-strings)

Comment: insted of `{"quantity":{"$gte":3}}` you could write,
`"this.quantity >=  3"`   , you can take a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039358/mongodb-gt-lt-operators-with-prices-stored-as-strings)

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty  i'm doing an aggregation..things are different from find(),it is not working in aggregation